# JUnit with Spring and Hibernate do not load configuration properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have a unit test java class file where I need to use both Spring and Hibernate.

Here is the top of the module:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:server-data-config.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
    // Other code follows
```

As you can see I load the context configuration for Spring from server-data-config.xml

It contains the following configuration that requires a session factory:

```
<bean id="txnManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now I get the following expection on session factory:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

That's because my session factory is defined in hibernate.cfg.xml and I'm not doing anything to load it:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        Some stuff here
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Should I add some annotation in my unit test java class in order to read hibernate.cfg.xml? How can I fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in your xml where the hibernate config can be found

spring config:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
    <value>file:src/hibernate.cfg.xml</value> // your hibernate.cfg.xml location
    </property>
    </bean>
```

You could take this approach in java :

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log exception!
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession()
            throws HibernateException {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

since with the latter approach you have the sessionfactory you can then configure it like so:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
        .configure("/persistence/hibernate.cfg.xml")
        .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to load hibernate.cfg.xml directly with an annotation?

Comment: Possibly but not that I know of.